# Resizing UITableViewCell content width automatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, autoresize

I have some code that creates a table cell with a slider. It's pretty straightforward and it sizes well on the iPhone. I've anonymized it a bit here:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foo"] autorelease];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
CGRect contentViewFrame = cell.contentView.frame;
CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 280, contentViewFrame.size.height);
UISlider* slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
UIImage* minimumImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"min.png"];
UIImage* maximumImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"max.png"];
slider.minimumValueImage = minimumImage;
slider.maximumValueImage = maximumImage;
slider.value = 0.5f;
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
[slider release];
```

Of course, this is incorrectly sized for the iPad. So my first thought was to set the `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. Problem solved, right? Nope. Now on the iPhone, the width of the slider-plus-images content is less than 280 and so it doesn't go right to the end -- it ends up about 20 pixels short.

On the iPad, the same thing -- the width of the `UISlider` automatically resizes to about 20 pixels short of the end of the cell.

Perhaps the auto resize flag is paying attention to the non-existent `accessoryView` of the cell? I tried setting it to `nil` explicitly, but I think it's `nil` by default, so nothing changed.

**I'd like this cell's content to resize automatically to be the "full" width of the cell, regardless of device and orientation. Is there an easy way to do this?**

Answer (score 10):

It works exactly how you described. I am inclined to think it's iOS bug. On iPAD when you create new UITableViewCell its width set for 320. hardcoded(!) both view and contentView. It does not resize properly if set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`. I had it set to view.frame.size.width/2 with funny results: on iPhone it's 160, on iPad it's 608!!!

I ended up manually resizing my cells and their content.

Comment: Yeah, looks like its is always 320 when first created

Comment: It's not a bug, the `contentMode` is just wrong. see below.

Answer (score 6):

Bit late but i found the solution of the same question today, but you need to create a custom UITableViewCell. 
Then you can overwrite the function

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [dateLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(10.f, 16.f, 80.f, 12.f)];
    [textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(106.f, 16.f, contentView.frame.size.width-105.f + 1.f, 12.f)];
}
```

In that function the self.frame.size.width is the actual one.
And it works with rotation of the device, too.

Comment: You don't need to manually set those subviews frames. You just need to call `[super layoutSubviews];` in there, that will make subviews autoresize correctly.

Comment: You do, if you have custom subviews (in your custom cell)

Comment: on layoutSubviews, docs state "You should not call this method directly." Instead call setNeedsLayout

Comment: +1 for overriding layoutSubviews, custom subviews, and not calling the method directly. Additionally, when using the "grouped" display for the table, you should be using `contentView.frame` instead of `self.frame`, as `self.frame` appears to return the width of the table, and in grouped mode the cells are narrower than the table. (pardon my ObjC, I use MonoTouch and C#, so the calls are different. concepts are the same).

Comment: As @cod3monk3y said--when using cells, you should put your content in `contentView`, not the cell itself. Resize based on the bounds of `contentView`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to tell the resizing system to "stick" the object a fixed distance from the right edge (where it's not resizing far enough).  If you experiment with IB you can create a view that resizes in width and is fixed to the right side.

Do you have UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin set as well?

Comment: I don't have `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` set. Can you explain a bit more how to do this programatically? The code posted above is anonymized but is exactly what I have now.

Answer (score 3):

Set your cell's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.